# Is there a way to remove margins/padings for specific pages in Hugo Academic?

Tags: html, css, hugo, blogdown

I have an `iframe` object in the index.md page of [Hugo Academic](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic) website that I want to be at the full width of the page without margins (screenshot attached). I added this code to .md file:

```html
<style>
iframe {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
</style>
```

However 0 padding is already where the `iframe` is at the moment, so I can move it to the right, but not to the left.

Can it be adjusted for the specific objects/pages?

`iframe` looks like this:

```html
<iframe src="https://ruslankl.shinyapps.io/roc_simulation/" width=1000 height=1000" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CbKN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and found [this article](https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/) with several better solutions. My original solution worked, but it made the iframe float on top of the rest of the content, and we do not want that.

So, thanks to the article mentioned above, I came up with the following that works on your website:

```css
iframe {
  height: 1000px; /* Set this to the height you want the iframe to have. */
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

Note the comment after the `height`. You need to set a fixed height on the iframe to prevent the iframe's content from being cut off. I first set it to `650px` which according to my calculations is the height of the website it loads, but then I got a scrollbar, and I assume you would prefer no scrolling.

To quote the article on how it actually works:

> *The idea here is: push the container to the exact middle of the browser window with left: 50%;, then pull it back to the left edge with negative -50vw margin.*

And as a final note, the `vw` unit is a *viewport unit*, more specifically the width of the viewport, where `100vw` is 100% of the viewport width.

**Original answer below:**

I have not tested this with the Academic theme, but on my own site (built on Hugo, but that should not matter) this makes the iframe the full width of the page, regardless of any margins or paddings on the content:

```css
iframe {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

With the use of the `position: absolute`, the iframe will be placed as close to the left of the window as possible (thanks to `left: 0`). Then we use `width: 100%` to make it fill the page.

You should also consider adding a class or an id to the iframe, so you can use that for styling instead of the `<iframe>` element, just in case you happen to have more than one iframe on the same page.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks so much:)

Comment: Well, it works as expected, but `absolute` positioning places <iframe> on top of other objects on the page. Could't find a way to fix it yet

Comment: I was afraid that would happen. I can take a closer look if you post a link to your site!

Comment: Sure! Here is the test [page](https://defme.xyz/project/test/), here is the [.md file](https://github.com/ruslan-kl/defme.xyz/blob/master/content/project/test/index.md). I was able to fix it with kinda lame approach - adding dozens of `<br>` tags haha. It does the trick for the laptop screen, but if the screen resolution is smaller (for example, on the smartphone) it overlays other objects on the page. If by any chance you know the better solution, please let me know:)

Comment: Thank you! I found a better solution and have updated my answer now. Let me know if the new code works for you!

Comment: Damn, that's amazing! It works! [Example page](https://defme.xyz/project/norm-binom/) and [source code](https://github.com/ruslan-kl/defme.xyz/blob/master/content/project/norm-binom/index.md). I wish I could upvote your solution twice haha :)